# How can I switch database connection and share it to model in Golang? (Revel + Gorm)

Tags: go, revel, go-gorm

I want to setup Database sharding like https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus in Revel + Gorm(or any other ORM in Golang).

I will get db connection string in **security filter** (which was a custom filter, added after revel's param filter). Now I need to switch db connection in next custom filter called **db filter**

And also need to implement db connection pool in revel application start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is prepare you DB connection on the init (only call once) :

```
db1, err := gorm.Open(dbdriver, dboption) //your main server
db2, err := gorm.Open(dbdriver, dboption) //your sharding 1
db3, err := gorm.Open(dbdriver, dboption) //your sharding 2
```

And on your db filter just choose the between db1, db2, or db3 you want to be used by your model. Thats all.

Gorm already make the pool for you, so you don't need to take care.

Comment: I don't know the shard db options like host, db name until request cross the security filter. So I cannot create db connection inside init

Comment: why you don't know? is it application that you will build, no?

Comment: I will get user database details from other service (cluster service) . That will be fetched in security filter.

Comment: But I believe you have a list of the DB server, so you can connect to all DB you have. And when any request come, just select which DB to use. I still don't know why you don't know your DB.

Comment: DB server list maintain in other service. One db server will have 300 db 's.  Suppose we have 5 db server means, is it need to create 1500 gorm.open? Is it right to do?